# How and why a class method is evoked when a class instance is created

Tags: python, django

I am not able to understand why and how **RegistrationForm** class method **clean_username** is evoked when I am creating class instance in my view.py

**my form.py**

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    firm_name         = forms.CharField()
    username              = forms.CharField()
    def clean_username(self):
        print "inside clean_username ..I don know how this called"
        if db.firm.find(username =self.cleaned_data['username']):
            raise forms.ValidationError((u'This username is already taken. Please choose another.'))
        return self.cleaned_data['username']
```

**My view.py**

```
def main(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/thanks/")
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, "registration.html", {
        'form': form,
    })
```

this gets printed "inside clean_username ..I don know how this called"

According to my understanding the class method clean_username() should not be run until evoked like form.clean_username()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is called automatically by django, as part of form and field validation.

See the [django documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/):

> Validation of a Form is split into several steps, which can be
>   customized or overridden:
>
> The `clean_<fieldname>()` method in a form subclass – where `<fieldname>` is replaced with the name of the form field attribute.
>   This method does any cleaning that is specific to that particular
>   attribute, unrelated to the type of field that it is. This method is
>   not passed any parameters.

Comment: Thanks..I was freaking out when the method was called directly